# Net View using Runspace in Powershell

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, network-programming, runspace

I am currently being challenged with trying to enable a script (which takes multiple machines and lists the shares on each machine) to operate with multiple threads using a Runspace. My share query is done using NET VIEW, this portion of my code works perfectly as part of my existing script which runs sequentially.

However as I am scanning my entire corporate domain, parallel querying makes sense.
After looking at a few wiki's, I land up with the code below, however this seems to execute and just hang. I have tinkered around with the code with no visible success.
My small sample of machines are online, as I execute a test before hand to verify this.

This is my first attempt at a Runspace, I am really not sure where I am going wrong and would really appreciate the assistance.

Thank you

```
$computers = @('computer1','computer2','computer3','computer4','computer5')
$pool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, 50)
$pool.ApartmentState = "MTA"
$pool.open()
$runspaces = @()  

$scriptblock = {
param([string]$m)

Write-Host $computers.Length
$pattern = [regex]"(.+)\s+(Disk)"
$shares_array  = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$shares = net view $m | foreach {

if ($_ -match $pattern)
{
   $b = "\\$m\$($matches[1])"
   $shares_array.Add($b)

}
}}

ForEach($m in $computers) {
$runspace = [PowerShell]::Create()
$null = $runspace.AddScript($scriptblock)
$null = $runspace.AddArgument($m)
$runspaces += [PSCustomObject]@{ Pipe = $runspace; Status = $runspace.BeginInvoke() }
}

while ($runspaces.Status -ne $null)
{
$completed = $runspaces | Where-Object { $_.Status.IsCompleted -eq $true }
foreach ($runspace in $completed)
{
    $runspace.Pipe.EndInvoke($runspace.Status)
    $runspace.Status = $null
}
}

$pool.Close()
$pool.Dispose()
```

Comment: Did you try [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6) - it can run a command against multiple systems at once and produce a consolidated result set.  Also check out [Get-SmbShare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/get-smbshare?view=win10-ps) instead of `new view` - this can also run against remote computers.

Comment: I have tried **Invoke-Command** however I get an access denied. I do not want to try using CredSSP delegation of my credentials as the scan will possibly include compromised machines as well. **Get-SmbShare** doesnt work for me. Net View works, but the parallel execution is what I need assistance with.